# Do I need a junction box to direct-wire these 4' LED lamps?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture, led, nec

I bought [these](https://smile.amazon.com/Barrina-Integrated-Daylight-Warehouse-Workshop/dp/B07G2Q4VZN) Barrina 4' LED T8-form-factor lamps off of Amazon. I plan on installing them in our basement by attaching them to bare joists and wiring them to a new 15A circuit.

They include a little 6" adapter cable (seen in the 5th product photo) that allows you to direct wire the lamp to a 120V circuit.

[image: product image of direct wire adapter plugged into lamp]

It's my understanding that any 120V "junctions" requiring wire nuts or wagos between lines and loads need to be contained within a metal junction box. With traditional shop lights and fluorescent fixtures, this is usually attained by the Romex being shoved into its own metal housing, securing all the connections within. These lights have no accessible housing, though.

Is there any safe, NEC-approved way to attach this product directly to a circuit without a junction box? Given how short the adapter is, how would you guys direct-wire these with the hardware provided?

Thanks

---

ETA: Here's a closeup of the tail.
[image: image of direct wire adapter]
[image: closeup of plug end]
[image: closeup of wire end]

Here's a closeup of the label on the light fixture itself:
[image: light fixture label]

And here's the only documentation provided.
[image: manual front]
[image: manual back]

Comment: Can you post pictures of the labeling on the cordage "tail" provided as well as any listing or labeling marks on the product itself please?

Comment: There are approved splices for NM-B(Romex) to NM-B that can be hidden. However, the tail on the light doesn’t look like NM-B so I don’t think that can be used

Comment: The lights aren't NEC approved.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the requested pictures to the post.

Comment: @DoxyLover Just curious, what are some approved splices for Romex cable? And no, I don't think it's NM-B. The conductor itself is stranded copper, maybe 18awg at most.

Comment: @Harper  I guess I should probably return these and get something different if I want the basement lighting to pass the next inspection. Is there an easy way to tell if something's NEC approved when shopping online?

Comment: @J.D.Mallen -- don't shop Amazon, eBay, or AliExpress, for starters -- and what you're after is a NRTL *listing* and *labeling*

Comment: one of these, for the US. Being "Natinally recognized" means the list may vary by nation, but many of them are recognized by many nations... https://www.osha.gov/nationally-recognized-testing-laboratory-program/current-list-of-nrtls

Comment: Thanks guys. Knew something felt unsafe with these. I'll return them and get something NRTL listed.

Comment: @jdmallen NM-B splice: https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FEPP-3384%7F1904%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_EPP-3384_1904.pdf%7FA22899-000

Comment: NRTL listing means UL, CSA or ETL are the ones you're likely to see. CSA, BSI, TUV are simply the national "UL" of Canada, Britain and Germany). All of them are certifying the light complies with US safety standards, which are curated by UL. You don't have any NRTL marks on that piece... CE and FCC aren't NRTLs and they're both fake marks lol.  CE is a Euro "promise of self-certification" so only meaningful from a manufacturer who ships from inside the EU.

Comment: The reason Amazon can offer things so cheesy, oops cheap is because they do not comply with the standards required in the US, I am glad you plan to return them, even the big box stores sell junk but at least it is listed for use in the US. Break down get a listed product (this doesn’t include CE) but others have provided examples of UL, TUV and others , with LED’s if you want something that will last more than 90 to 300 days get a DLC approved lamp. Design Light Consortium requires. 5 year warranty on the devices it endorses not the 90 day ones that the big orange box store sells or others FYI